# Python: How to sort row wise strings in columns of a df?

Tags: python, pandas, sorting

I have a df containing a column with strings separated by commas which i try to sort alphabetically.

For a simple list like

```
data = ['B', 'C', 'A', 'D']
```

I would use something like

```
', '.join(sorted(data))
```

which works fine.
However, for my df which Looks like

```
d = {'col1': [1, 2], 'col2': ['D, D, A, C', 'B, A, B, A']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
```

I am not able to sort row wise the col2 alphabetically.
I tried so far

```
print ', '.join(sorted(df['col2']))
```

which returns a complete sorting but not row wise.
My expected result is:

```
res = {'col1': [1, 2], 'col2': ['A, C, D, D', 'A, A, B, B']}
result = pd.DataFrame(data=res)
```

Thanks, for your ideas!

Answer (score 1):

You can use apply as follows:

```
df["col2"] = df.col2.apply(lambda x: ", ".join(sorted(x.split(", "))))
```

---

**Explanation:**

- `df.col2.apply(..)` iterates through the rows of `df.col2`
- For each row, it splits the string into a list using `x.split(", ")`
- Each list is then sorted, using `sorted(x.split(", "))`
- The sorted list is then concatenated to a string and assigned back to the row using

  ```
  ", ".join(sorted(x.split(", ")))
  ```

---

**output:**

```
   col1        col2
0     1  A, C, D, D
1     2  A, A, B, B
```

Answer (score 0):

another way would be,

Method -1

```
df['col2'] = [', '.join(sorted (val )) for val in df.col2.str.split(', ').values] # split the value by , sort the values and combined it with `, `
print(df)
```

Method -2:

```
df['col2'] = [', '.join(sorted(x.split(', '))) for x in df['col2']]
print(df) # for each value in cell split the value by `, ` sort the value and join by `, `
```

O/P:

```
   col1        col2
0     1  A, C, D, D
1     2  A, A, B, B
```